# Couchbase N1QL: How to aggregate and join from the same bucket with an array of keys

Tags: couchbase, sql++, nosql

Assume:

Album Document:

```
{ 
    "albumName": "my album",
    "photos": [photo1Id, photo2Id, photo3Id]
}
```

Photo document:

```
{
    "photoName": "photoName1.img";
    "photoId": "photo1Id";
    "otherData": "Some other data"
}
```

where the key of the Photo Document is the same as the photoId.

I want to make a SELECT statement that will have this output:

```
{ 
    "albumName": "my album",
    "photos": [{
        "photoName": "photoName1.img";
        "photoId": "photo1Id";
        "otherData": "Some other data"
    },{
        "photoName": "photoName2.img";
        "photoId": "photo2Id";
        "otherData": "Some other data"
    },{
        "photoName": "photoName3.img";
        "photoId": "photo3Id";
        "otherData": "Some other data"
    }]
}
```

Is this possible or do I have to create multiple selects?

Answer (score 4):

Use the [NEST clause](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/from.html#story-h2-5) to output the photos array in the result document.

Example : (I use type to filter on your document type but it's perhaps not your case)

```
SELECT * FROM bucket albums
NEST bucket photos ON KEYS albums.photos
WHERE albums.type='Album'
```